# Возможно ли внутри одного проекта отметить 2 source root папки так, чтобы часть модулей проверяла первую, а часть - вторую?

Tags: python, django, импорт

Есть структура проекта:

```
├─ parser 
│  ├─ apps
│  │  ├─ script_1
│  ├─ module_to_import_1
├─ server
│  ├─ apps
│  │  ├─ script_2
│  ├─ module_to_import_2
```

Есть ли способ настроить относительный импорт для обоих скриптов так, чтобы:

- script_1 воспринимал как source root 'parser'
- script_2 воспринимал как source root 'server'

Или это можно реализовать только по схеме:

- script_1 использует абсолютный импорт
- script_2 использует относительный импорт

ВАЖНО: структура проекта намеренно упрощенна для визуального восприятия, поэтому ответы вида:

"Воспользуйся относительным импортом в обоих случаях"
(Воспользоваться относительным импортом в одном из случаев - решение, которое я предполагаю, но интересно есть ли более оптимальный путь)

"Замени apps на apps_server"

Не подходят.